# Messagebox does not show if there rows affected in the database C# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I already successfully updated my database using this code :

```
        private void btnUpdt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect_db();

        string name = txtName.Text;
        string rep = txtRep.Text;
        string contact = txtCntctNum.Text;
        string address = txtAdd.Text;
        string email = txtEmail.Text; 

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE clients SET client_Rep = @rep, client_Address = @address, client_CntctNum = @contact, client_Email = @email WHERE client_Name = @name";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rep", rep);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            cmd.Connection = connect;

            MySqlDataReader editClients = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            txtName.Clear();
            txtRep.Clear();
            txtAdd.Clear();
            txtCntctNum.Clear();
            txtEmail.Clear();

            txtName.ReadOnly = false;

            btnReg.Text = "REGISTER";
            btnReg.Name = "btnReg";
            btnReg.Click -= this.btnUpdt_Click;
            btnReg.Click += this.btnReg_Click;

            if (editClients.HasRows)
            {
                while (editClients.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Client Successfully Updated!");
                }
            }                        

            if (editClients.Read())
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                connect.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

What I dont understand is that this certain MessageBox.Show("Client Successfully Updated!"); did not show despite the successful update. Is there anything I missed?

**EDIT**
I was trying to count number of rows affected from the update query and show the messagebox if there are any rows changed in the database.

Comment: Better use this kind of logic
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE clients SET client_Rep = @@rep, client_Address = @@address, client_CntctNum = @@contact, client_Email = @@email WHERE client_Name = @@name; SELECT 'Client Successfully Updated!!'";
and then use executescalar to get value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try to use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
and comment out mysqldatareader related code

```
       int numberOfrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       if (numberOfrows > 0)
        {
             //means update is sucessful
                MessageBox.Show("Client Successfully Updated!");

        } 
        btnReg.Click -= this.btnUpdt_Click;
        btnReg.Click += this.btnReg_Click;
```

Comment: still no good. Actually I could put the messagebox without the if statements and it will show. Its just that I really want to put it under a condition to only show it if there are any rows affected after the update.

Comment: is the update successful? i mean is the data in the row is really updated?coz i think you dont have ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: yes it really updated successfully. because I can see it on my datagridview and I checked mysql workbench. The row is updated.

Comment: i updated my answer please check if that helps you :)

Comment: I tried using your answer but it shows "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first". But the update is still successful.

Comment: please try comment out `ExecuteReader();` related code

Comment: it works! Thank you very much! So this means ExecuteReader() is useless on UPDATE queries? I have to read more on the documentation make sure I dont miss anything.

Comment: oh! im really happy that it did help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of rows affected by your query, then I think you can also use:

```
EditClients.RowsAffected
```

Property to do the same.
if EditClients.RowsAffected are greater than or equal to 1 then there will be change in rows.
Hope this helps.